# What is the difference between まだしません and まだしていません?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

These are the two sentences in question:

> いいえ、まだしません。
>
> いいえ、まだしていません。

From my understanding they both mean something like "No, I didn't yet" or even simply "No, not yet" but there must be a difference in translation/meaning or application that I'm missing obviously based around the ています which is present continuous correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of these two sentences is likely to be different.

*Plain negative:*

> (1) いいえ、まだしない。
> "No, (I) do not do it (habitually) yet." *(yet: habitual)*
> "No, (I) will not do it yet." *(yet: habitual)*
> "No, (I) still do not do it (habitually)." *(still: habitual)*
> "No, (I) still will not do it." *(still: future)*

*Negative ている:*

> (2) いいえ、まだしていない。
> "No, (I) have not done it yet." *(yet: stative)*
> "No, (I) am not doing it yet." *(yet: progressive)*
> "No, (I) am not doing (habitually) it yet." *(yet: habitual)*
> "No, (I) still have not done it." *(still: stative)*
> "No, (I) am still not doing it." *(still: progressive)*
> "No, (I) am still not doing it (habitually)." *(still: habitual)*

**Examples:**

> 「宿題は終わった？」 "Did you finish your homework?"
> 「いいえ、まだしていません。」 "No, I haven't done it yet." *(yet: stative)*

`まだしません` would be wrong here, because that would mean "I am not doing my homework (regularly/habitually) yet.", or "No, I am still not going to do my homework (regularly/habitually)." or "No (I) am still not going to do it." none of which are an answer to the question.

> 息子はまだ（毎日）歩かない。
> "My son does not walk (every day) yet." *(yet: habitual)*
> "My son still does not walk (every day)." *(still: habitual)*
>
> （昨日から）息子はまだ歩いていない。
> "My son has not walked yet (since yesterday)." *(yet: stative)*
> "My son still hasn't walked (since yesterday)." *(still: stative)*
>
> （立ち上がったばかりなので）息子はまだ歩いていない。
> "(My son just stood up a second ago,) so he is not walking yet." *(yet: progressive)*
> "(My son just stood up a second ago,) so he still is not walking." *(still: progressive)*
>
> 息子はまだ（毎日）歩いていない。
> "My son is not walking (every day) yet." *(yet: habitual)*
> "My son is still not walking (every day)." *(still: habitual)*

Here is an example sentence which allows all the different interpretations. I use some extra pieces of text to help disambiguate the ていない sentences semantically. (I couldn't think of a nice example for する that allows all interpretations, so I went with 歩く instead -- I hope this isn't confusing.)

Comment: Is that what they teach まだしない means in the world Japanese as a foreign language?  It is not even close to what it means here in Japan.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya Thank you for your comment. I thought about it more, and have tried to improve my answer (though it seems to be getting very long as a result...). I am not sure if I have addressed your specific concern.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya: It would be far more helpful to state what `まだしない` *does* mean than only saying it doesn't mean what's written in the answer.

Comment: I'm interested in clarification too.

Comment: Sure, writing an answer is more helpful than leaving a quick comment saying something is wrong.  But it also takes a lot more time and effort, and I think it's wrong to demand that time and effort of others.  So I appreciate quick comments.  Even if they don't explain what the correct answer is, they're a signal to other readers that this isn't it.  (Of course, such comments should ideally be written **tactfully**.)